# Get memory and RAM details of installed android applications

Tags: android, package-managers

I am making an android application to get list of all apllication, their memory details and RAM used for application. I used this link

[Get installed Applications with Name, Package Name, Version and Icon](http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-installed-applications-with-name-package-name-version-and-icon)

Now I want to get memory details of android applications.
I try this code

```
MemoryInfo mi = new MemoryInfo();
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(mi);
long availableMegs = mi.availMem / 1048576L;
```

I am getting the info like app logo,app name,version,update time, package name, feautures, permissions.

But I want to get memory usage,size etc(hardware info) of each app.

I searched a lot and get the answer `public int getMemoryClass ()` from [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) but it giving 64mb for all appplication

Comment: Sunny: check updated code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:-

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
MemoryInfo memoryInfo = new ActivityManager.MemoryInfo();
activityManager.getMemoryInfo(memoryInfo);

Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.availMem " + memoryInfo.availMem + "\n" );
Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.lowMemory " + memoryInfo.lowMemory + "\n" );
Log.i(TAG, " memoryInfo.threshold " + memoryInfo.threshold + "\n" );

List<RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

Map<Integer, String> pidMap = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for (RunningAppProcessInfo runningAppProcessInfo : runningAppProcesses)
{
    pidMap.put(runningAppProcessInfo.pid, runningAppProcessInfo.processName);
}

Collection<Integer> keys = pidMap.keySet();

for(int key : keys)
{
    int pids[] = new int[1];
    pids[0] = key;
    android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo[] memoryInfoArray = activityManager.getProcessMemoryInfo(pids);
    for(android.os.Debug.MemoryInfo pidMemoryInfo: memoryInfoArray)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, String.format("** MEMINFO in pid %d [%s] **\n",pids[0],pidMap.get(pids[0])));
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPrivateDirty() + "\n");
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalPss() + "\n");
        Log.i(TAG, " pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty(): " + pidMemoryInfo.getTotalSharedDirty() + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,but it's giving the info of system. i want info of each app installed.

Comment: Hi, Ameer, Did you find any solution for the same if yes then please post your code

Answer (score 0):

Working code to get the information about the Apps installed on the device and the app size as well.. I have put a toast of it. Implementation may be as one's requirement is

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getPackages();
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.path = p.applicationInfo.sourceDir;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

        File file = new File(newInfo.path);
        long sizeinByte = file.length();
        long sizeinMb = sizeinByte / (1024*1024);

        Toast.makeText(this,newInfo.appname + "\t"/*"\t" + newInfo.pname + "\t" + newInfo.versionName + "\t" + newInfo.versionCode + "\t" */+sizeinMb+"Mb",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res;
}
private class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private String path = "";
    private Drawable icon;

    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.i("Here",appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode + "\t" + path );
    }
}

}
```